How to exploit feedforward compensation for a system with transport delay?
I have a combination of a feedback control loop and feedforward compensation

where $\tilde{E}$ represents a fluctuation of the system input (namely a input voltage of a dc-dc converter) which is directly measured. The $\tilde{E}$ is basically a step change or a sine with a given frequency.
The transfer function in the feedforward path can be found as
$H_{ff}(s) = \frac{W(s)}{G(s)}$.
In my particular case following holds
$G(s) = \frac{K_1}{s\cdot\tau + 1}\cdot e^{-s\cdot T_d}$
$W(s) = \frac{K_2}{s\cdot\tau + 1}$.
Based on that I have
$H_{ff}(s) = \frac{K_2}{K_1}\cdot e^{s\cdot T_d}$.
It means that for the feedforward compensation I would need a time shift forward (i.e. non-causal system which can be realized neither in continuous nor in digital domain). My question is how can be this time shift forward approximated in digital control? Is it e.g. possible to use appropriately designed lead compensator for that purpose exploiting its ability to bring phase lead?

What is the signal $\tilde{E}$? Can it be modeled or predicted into the future?

It's a fluctuation of the system input (namely a input voltage of a dc-dc converter). This input is directly measured.

But can any assumptions be made about it? Do you assume that it is fully stochastic are can it be (partially) modeled?

I assume step changes and sine with a fixed frequency (e.g. $300,\mathrm{Hz}$).

The forward delay is not causal operator and cannot be implemented for general signals. However, if you have a model for that signal, predictors can be designed in the same way it is done for the control of systems with input delays. Alternatively, if you have assume a preview of the signal(i.e. you know its future values over a certain horizon), then you can directly use those future values in the design.

@KBS thank you for your reaction. I am sorry but I haven't understood your idea with exploiting the predictor. May I ask you for explanation?

If you have a model, you can use that model to predict the future values of the signal.

If you do not have any model nor preview, you can try something alone those lines. I am not sure this will work in practice, but I would say that it is worth looking into.
First consider $H_{ff}(s)=Z(s)\dfrac{K_1}{K_2}$ where $Z(s)$ is a rational and proper transfer function to be designed. In this case, we get that the transfer from $\tilde E$ and $I_L$ is given by
$$
\dfrac{K_2}{1+s\tau}\dfrac{1-Z(s)e^{-sT_d}}{1+D(s)G(s)}.
$$
You said that you have step changes and a fixed frequency, say $\omega_d$ In first case, you want the transfer to be zero at zero. So, you need $Z(0)=1$. In the other case, you need $1-Z(j\omega_d)e^{-j\omega_dT_d}=0$, which is equivalent to $Z(j\omega_d)=e^{j\omega_dT_d}$. Now, you can try to design to design a stable transfer function that satisfies those interpolation conditions.
Note that I am not sure whether such a transfer function exists.
